# (jquery) How would I convert this contains declaration to the "not" equivalent?

Tags: jquery

```
var x =$( "span:Contains(" + searchTerm + ")" );
```

I want to change the above code so it is not contains, can't seem to get the syntax correct. Thank you for your time.

(Note: I am using a modified version of contains called "Contains" which is case insensitive if anyone is interested:

```
   jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
      .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

Comment: `$('span:not(:contains(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two alternatives it would seem:

```
 var x =$( "span:not(:Contains(" + searchTerm + "))" );

 var x =$( "span" ).not(":Contains(" + searchTerm + ")");
```

Note that I would would have preference for the latter one due to performance boost;